# Javascript Check if random number is the same as last

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a number of tiles that I am using javascript to toggle a class on a random tile every 2 seconds. I want to add a check so that it doesn't toggle the same tile twice in a row. something like this, but this doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
var gcFlip = $('.flip').find('div');
var sameImg;
function flip()
{
    if (gcFlip.length >= 1)
   {
        var nextImg = gcFlip[Math.floor(Math.random() * gcFlip.length)];
           while(nextImg === sameImg)
               {
                   var nextImg = gcFlip[Math.floor(Math.random() * gcFlip.length)];
               }
        nextImg = sameImg;
        $(nextImg).toggleClass('transition');
   }
}
setInterval(flip, 2000);
});
```

Comment: You don't initialize sameImg anywhere so it always will be undefined.

Comment: It should be `sameImg = nextImg` not `nextImg = sameImg;` and you have `var nextImg` twice

Comment: If you post-process random numbers, they're not random any more.  That may not make any difference in this case, but it is in general a bad practice.

Comment: @BobBrown: Excluding one value by picking a new by random is perfectly fine. It doesn't make the result less random.

Comment: @Guffa: I waited to talk to a real statistician to confirm what I thought, but yes, it does make the result less random.  What's going on here is sampling with replacement.  If a second draw of the same number is discarded, then the distribution of the sample is skewed.  (Depending on the size of the sample space, this will not happen often, but when it does happen, what OP is doing is *not* a random sample.)

Comment: @BobBrown: No, that's not what's going on. Sorry, whoever you talked to is mistaken. *If* the same number was supposed to have the same chance as any other number, then removing it would give a skewed result, but in this case the same number *isn't* supposed to have the same chance, it's not supposed to be part of the draw at all.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues here (@a-wolff hit on a few keys),

1. Closure scope, moved gcFlip & currentImg outside the document ready function - nextImg was being redefined each time inside the loop.  Moved the flip() function out of being defined inside the doc ready f(x).
2. you were setting your 'current image' pointer before you transitioned and the assignment was flipped (no pun intended) so you were resetting nextImg to the current image before calling the transition.

This should be closer to what you're looking for.

```
var gcFlip;
var currentImg;

$(document).ready(function (){
    var gcFlip = $('.flip').find('div');
    setInterval(flip, 2000);
});

function flip()
{
    if (gcFlip.length >= 1)
    {
      var nextImg = gcFlip[Math.floor(Math.random() * gcFlip.length)];
      while(nextImg == currentImg)
      {
         nextImg = gcFlip[Math.floor(Math.random() * gcFlip.length)];
      }
      $(nextImg).toggleClass('transition');
      currentImg = nextImg;
    }
}
```